# What does $\Omega^\bullet(M)$ mean?

Tags: notation, differential-forms

What does $\Omega^\bullet(M)$ mean?

I know that $\Omega^k(M)$ is the set of all differential k-forms.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\Omega^\bullet(M) = \bigoplus_{k=0}^{\dim M} \Omega^k(M)$ is the space of all differential forms, which is $\mathbb Z$ graded by degree.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer! I'm reading this: http://www.math.ist.utl.pt/~acannas/Books/lsg.pdf (page 36, PDF page 44). There we have both $\Omega^\bullet$ and $\Omega^\*$. So what is the difference?

Comment: There really is no difference.  $\bullet$ and $*$ are often used interchangeably when denoting $\mathbb Z$-graded objects.  $\bullet$ may be the better notation though since $*$ is also used for dual.